# How to retrieve YUI Rich Text Editor's content via Javascript?

Tags: editor, yui

I have a problem with `document.getElementById('editor').value`, because I can't get the value. The textarea of YUI Editor is not a normal TextArea.

```
<script>
function viewValue
{
   alert(document.getElementById('editor').value);
}
</script>
```

textarea:

```
<div class="editor" > 
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor">            
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Documentation: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/#getdata

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    //Put the HTML back into the text area
    oEditor.saveHTML();
    //The var html will now have the contents of the textarea
    var html = oEditor.get('element').value;
    alert(html);
</script>
```